# Can miners choose which transactions to mine?

Tags: transaction-selection, non-standard-transaction

I'm curious if miners can choose which transactions to mine?  I know that there are limits to the minimum size of a transaction fee (around 5400 satoshis) but I'm wondering if miners can ignore those limits for certain transactions.  For example, if I gave a mining pool a list of addresses and offered an incentive to them to mine them even though the transaction was non-standard, could they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that there are limits to the minimum size of a transaction fee (around 5400 satoshis)

Actually, [some transactions can sent for free](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Sending).

> For example, if I gave a mining pool a list of addresses and offered an incentive to them to mine them even though the transaction was non-standard, could they do it?

Absolutely. A miner can include any transaction that doesn't break network rules, for any reason.

Comment: Then what happened if at the same time, one miner sends a block solved with transaction #1#2#3 and another sends a block solved with transaction  #1#4#5: which one is the first to enter blockchain? Is the #1 transaction double confirmed?N